# Setting --keep-changes as default for `hg qpush` and `hg qpop`

Tags: mercurial, default, mq, mercurial-queue

Mercurial Queues recently got a new feature, which allows mq patches to be pushed and popped when there are local changes, provided the patches don't conflict with the local changes. This is controlled by the `--keep-changes` flag. I'd like to make this behavior the default. Generally, I avoid setting defaults, since that would mean `hg` works differently on my machine than on other machines, but in this case it seems harmless.

`hg help qpop` says, for example

```
With --keep-changes, abort only if the uncommitted files overlap with
    patched files.
[...]
    --keep-changes tolerate non-conflicting local changes
```

So, can someone tell what to put in `.hgrc` so that `--keep-changes` is default for `qpush` and `qpop`?

See [Bug 2780 - qpop should work if the local changes and the mq patches are unrelated](http://bz.selenic.com/show_bug.cgi?id=2780) for the history of this feature. It is possible there is no option to set this, in which case it is less useful. There isn't even a one letter alias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The defaults section of hgrc should do what you want (untested though):

```
[defaults]
qpush = --keep-changes
qpop  = --keep-changes
```

But.... defaults are "depreciated", and people are encouraged to use aliases instead. I don't think that will mean they disappear though, it would "break work-flows" which is a mortal sin in mercurial development.

Comment: I think in this specific context, this default is Ok, because it is always what I want, at least I cannot think of a circumstance in which I would not want it to apply. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Read about [alias](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hgrc.5.html#alias) section and pay special attention to note in this chapter

> ### Note
>
> It is possible to create aliases with the same names as existing
>   commands, which will then override the original definitions. This is
>   almost always a bad idea!

Comment: I know about aliases, and don't want to use that. I hoped there was some provision for a setting for `==keep-changes`. As I recall, there was some discussion about a setting at the time. Maybe it was never introduced?